# Require.js nested requires

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm trying to use requireJS but I want to build a hierarchy of dependencies: `main` requires `obr.platcom` and `obr.platcom` requires `obr` (for example).

I have this hierarchy of files:

```
- index.html
-> js
   - main.js
   -> lib
      - jquery.js
      - require.js
   -> obr [my own 'libraries']
      - obr.js
      - obr.platcom.js
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <title>Platcom</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    require(["obr/obr.platcom"], function() {
        obr.hola();
        var myPlatcom = obr.platcom();
        myPlatcom.test();
    });
});
```

obr.js

```
var obr = {};
obr.hola = function() {
    alert('Hola OBR');
};
```

obr.platcom.js

```
require(["obr.js"],function() {
    obr.platcom = function(params) {
        var that = {};

        var test = function test() {
            alert('Hola Platcom!');
        }

        that.test = test;
        return that;
    }
});
```

If I require both `obr` and `obr.platcom` files in the `main` all works, but if I use this nested style I receive the next error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: obr is not defined       main.js:3
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, you've done several things wrong.

1. You need to specify as an argument the dependency you're injecting. For example, `require(["obr/obr.platcom"], function() {` won't do much unless you specify *how* the required module can be called. You should need this:

   ```
   require(["obr/obr.platcom"], function( obr ) {
   ```

   This way, you know in which variable your required object is.
2. The `obr.js` variables are in the global scope. You need to wrap them in a `require` or `define` function call. The following would work:

   ```
   define(function() {
       var obr = {};
       obr.hola = function() {};
       return obr;
   });
   ```

   You may have noticed some things that are wrong with your last file.
3. If you want your module to be imported somewhere, you have to **define** it. So you have to use the `define` function, not the `require` one. And the `define` function must return an object. Here is a fixed `obr.platcom.js` file:

   ```
   // If you don't use "define" for the obr.js file too, this won't work
   define(['obr'], function( obr ) {
       obr.platcom = function() {};

       // Don't forget to return the obr object, or the require of
       // the main file won't return anything
       return obr;
   });
   ```

This way, things are done the correct way. Or at least, the way require.js wants you to do stuff.

I hope this reveals you how require.js can be effectively used to easily separate your code in modules :)

Comment: +1, but in addition it's worth mentioning that if the DOM needs to be ready then take advantage of the domReady module as part of RequireJS - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload

Comment: Well, I usually put the script tag right before the closing body tag, so I never worried about this :-). Nice to know this domReady module though.

Comment: Well, because the loading of modules is async I can imagine it more common to add require in the head and need use of a domReady. I usually include it in the head to trigger loading of modules earlier.

Comment: Originally I was only trying to use requireJS as a simple "require" of files, instead of attach all files to index.html Then all this complexity and modules seems me too much, but I suppose that this is that requireJS does. There is another library to simply achieve that I was trying? But the way, thank you. This is very useful in any case.

Comment: About, domReady, what is the advantage of use it instead jQuery ready? Since I need to download additional code to use domReady I wouldn't like to do that if it is not really necessary.

Comment: The advantage is that it's "integrated", but you don't need it if you have jQuery. You should integrate jQuery into require.js btw :) http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: Apart from not needing to depend on a library, it also means that module loading can begin instantly, whether the DOM is ready or not. The modules will only be used when the DOM is ready. When wrapping the entire require call within a jQuery ready you're slowing this process down. I feel like I should back this up with a test but I don't have anything to hand.

Comment: To confirm my previous comment, I asked James Burke (author of requirejs) - https://twitter.com/jrburke/status/205325878245339136

Comment: @davidgnin If you do just require a script loader then there are *many* alternatives. http://microjs.com/#loader One of my favs is $script https://github.com/ded/script.js RequireJS does load scripts async but it's real intention is to be used with AMD