# Timing issues with overriding js functions across files

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my rails project, I've written a javascript function to override the default behaviour of an object in another defined in another file. The line that did this looked something like:

```
window.someObject.methodToOverride = function...
```

Initially this would get me a `cannot set property 'methodToOverride' of undefined` error, which I'm assuming was related to the a timing issue (with `someObject` not being setup yet). I was able to resolve the issue by chucking it in a jQuery `$(document).ready` function, but while that works, it seems a bit hacky to me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That depends on how the object is defined. If the object is also defined on document ready, then using document ready is the correct approach.

Comment: @KevinB Cool, that makes far too much sense. Going back and looking at the files again, I hadn't noticed that the object was set inside jQuery(function($) {...}), in which case ready is definitely correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're looking for [require.js](http://requirejs.org).  What it does is let you set up your code modularly, defining which module depends on which.  In your case, once it's set up, by putting a wrapper such as

```
require(["someObject"], function (someObject) {
    someObject.methodToOverride = function...
}
```

will make it so when you got to this function, require.js would dynamically load your someObject file, and when it was fully loaded, pass someObject as a parameter into the function you provided.  It can work with much more complicated examples, with any level and any number of dependencies, loading them no more than once on an as-needed basis.

You can find a lot more information on require.js all over SO, e.g.:

- [simple example for using require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485039/simple-example-for-using-require-js)
- [Require.js nested requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719355/require-js-nested-requires)

Comment: Interesting, will file that away for future reference. In this case though the issue was that I hadn't realised when the original object was defined.